# VBA Get column letter based on cell text and use as string

Tags: excel, vba, automation

I am trying to find a column letter based on a text ,contained in a cell. I managed to find the letter, but the next part is what bothers me. The column letter(declared as "trcol") is a part of a loop that goes through the table and copies certain values based on that column.So that column should be the target column to copy from.This is what i have so far:

```
Dim trcol as String
Workbooks.Open (ThisWorkbook.Path & workb)
Sheets(sh).Select
Set Cell = Cells.Find("Customer Score %", , xlValues, xlPart, , , False)
If Not Cell Is Nothing Then

  ColLetter = Split(Cell.Address, "$")(1)
     trcol = """ & ColLetter & """
    
     
Else
  MsgBox "I cannot find that text on this sheet"
End If
''''''''''''''''''''''
'the loop
''''''''''''''''''''''
Dim N As Long, i As Long

Workbooks.Open (ThisWorkbook.Path & workb)
N = Cells(Rows.Count, sccol).End(xlUp).Row


For i = 2 To N
Dim totalRnNum As Integer: totalRnNum = Range("F100").End(xlUp).Row
Dim totalVal As Double: totalVal = Cells(totalRnNum, 6).Value
Cells(i, **trcol**).Copy '''''''here i need to have the result of the search as trcol


Next i
```

Comment: `Cells` can be used with column *numbers*. Save the cell column number: `ColNumber = Cell.Column`  and use that: `Cells(i, ColNumber ).Copy`

Answer (score 0):

### Column Letter

- Column `XFD` has more than one letter so more accurately would be *column string* but you probably won't need to extract it ever. You can simply use `cell.Column` to get the column number and use it with `.Cells` as FunThomas already mentioned in the comments.
- This should cover some of the issues with your code most notably, you should:

  - use `Option Explicit`,
  - avoid using `Select` and any flavors of `Active`,
  - qualify your objects i.e. `Cells` refers to the active sheet which could be the wrong one.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
    
    ' Variables declared previously:
    Dim workb As String
    Dim sh As String
    Dim scCol As Long ' or As String?
    
    Dim pSep As String: pSep = Application.PathSeparator
    Dim FolderPath As String: FolderPath = ThisWorkbook.Path
    
    If Left(workb, 1) = pSep Then
         FolderPath = FolderPath & workb
    Else
         FolderPath = FolderPath & pSep & workb
    End If
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FolderPath)
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets(sh)
    
    Dim tcCell As Range
    Set tcCell = ws.Cells.Find("Customer Score %", , xlValues, xlPart)
    
    If tcCell Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Could not find that text on this sheet.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim trCol As Long: trCol = tcCell.Column
    
    Dim LastRow As Long: LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, scCol).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim ttCell As Range: Set ttCell = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp)
    Dim Total As Double: Total = ttCell.Value
    
    Dim i As Long
    
    For i = 2 To LastRow
        ws.Cells(i, trCol).Copy
    
    
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi guys,thank you. I amended my code as per @Vbasic2008 instructions. Everything works now.